Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail() - Laravel 11 Docs Include This Function With Example
When running this line
$usa_region = DB::table(self::REGIONS_TABLE)->where('slug', 'usa')->firstOrFail();


I get this error
local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::firstOrFail() at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:67)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(4390): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::throwBadMethodCallException('firstOrFail')
#1 /var/www/html/database/migrations/2024_10_31_173207_default_timezone_and_region_for_users_to_pst_usa.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->__call('firstOrFail', Array)


However in the Laravel 11 docs it shows you can use firstOrFail() with the query builder, despite it not being available in the past
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table
Why do the docs differ from the actual behavior?
Currently using "laravel/framework": "^11.28",

Are you using the latest version (11)? Prior to version 11, afaik firstOrFail is only available on Eloquent builders, not Query builders like your example

Using version 11 currently

This is a peculiar problem. I did some code diving and the firstOrFail() method is not present on the Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder class, only on Eloquent classes. However, the docs do indeed state that it should be possible. Looking at the documentation commit history, the part of the docs you refer to is committed as wip by Taylor, so it might not be done yet.
You could of course create an issue in the laravel/framework repository

You can see the commit here, if you're curious.

Here is the PR to update the docs https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/10010

Oh your right, I was still looking at the eloquent builder. There's no firstOrFail on query builder

apparently the maintainers of laravel don't think it's an issue and closed my PR https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/10010#issuecomment-2452729829, but it's still failing
https://www.loom.com/share/8d41a2cc46a64555b7e65b04a18340da

@DrewGallagher Did some more digging and it seems that the method was added in 11.30, meaning your version of Laravel does not yet support it. See the commit here. So I think running composer update laravel/framework should do the trick.

@geertjanknapen oh okay cool, thanks for looking :D

You can't use the firstOrFail method with the DB facade, the firstOrFail method only works with Eloquent models. You should use your model name to retrieve data from the database,
for example, If you are fetching data from the users table and its model is User, the correct code is:
User::where('slug', 'usa')->firstOrFail();

and you can't use the DB facade
DB::table('users)->where('slug', 'usa')->firstOrFail();


in the docs it says you can though that's the issue
